# Complex integration and Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

i was asked to calculate the following integral:
 $$\int_{|z|<1}\frac{1}{z^2\sinh(z)}\: dz$$
I was suggested to calculate the Laurent Series of the integrand function, but how does one determine such series? So far i've just done some manipulations, such $$\frac{1}{z^2\sinh(z)}=\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{2}{e^{z}-e^{-z}}$$ but i'm far away from finding a series. Can someone help me finding such series?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$z^2\sinh z = z^3\left(1+ \frac{z^2}{6} + \cdots\right)$$

Since we are finding a residue for a pole located at $0$, we can use geometric series to conclude that

$$\frac{1}{z^2\sinh z} = z^{-3}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{6} - \cdots\right) = \frac{1}{z^3} - \frac{1}{6z}+\cdots$$

which means the residue is $-\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm not familiar with the term residue, what does it have in common with the value of the integral?

Comment: @riemannfanboy Calculate $\oint z^n \:dz$ on the unit circle for all integer $n$ and tell me what you get.

Comment: the value of such integral on he unit circle is zero.

Comment: @riemannfanboy you didnt do it carefully enough, that's not true for all $n$

Comment: yes  u are correct. It is either zero or $2 \pi i$

Comment: @riemannfanboy and which $n$ has $2\pi i$ ? If you could decompose a function into a series $f(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ which terms would survive the integral?

Comment: the negative ones.

Comment: @riemannfanboy no that is not correct, there is only one value that survives.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not understanding...